# Measurement Protocol Events Showing Up In GA Real-Time Dashboard but not Content Dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am sending events to Google Analytics using Measurement Protocol. For a while (few days) these seemed to be showing up fine in both the Real-Time area of the Google Analytics Website and the Content->Events->Overview.

Now, they are still showing in the Real-Time page but the Content->Events->Overview shows no activity for over 5 days.

Would appreciate any ideas. Surely if they are showing up in Real-Time it shows that they are being correctly sent to the system?

Answer (score 2):

I think I answered my own question here - setting the cid parrameter to be a UUID seems to have done the trick, as per the docs:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#customs

As per some of their examples where 5555 is used:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference

Comment: Had a similar problem.  Switched to using RFC-compliant UUIDs.  Still having this problem.  You run into any other reasons why hits might be displayed in realtime reports but not make it into the 'historic' reports?