# Measurement Protocol hits showing up in realtime view, but not in reports

Tags: google-analytics

I've set up some analytics hits for tracking email opens and clicks but I'm having trouble generating reports in Analytics to view them.

When I check the params in the GA hitbuilder, (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) the URL is marked as valid, and I see the event in the GA realtime view, but I'm not seeing it in reports.

For Clicks, we run our analytics through Segment and I can confirm in their debugger that we fire an 'identify' event followed by a 'page' event, we also see in real-time > events view but not in behavior > events

I've checked the account and there are no filters set.

the open URL has these params:

```
v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&cc=some_email_identifier&cm=email&cn=same_for_all&cs=enrollment&ea=open&ec=email&el=enrollment&uid=some_user_id
```

and the click event routed through segment has these params:

```
?ajs_uid=some_user_id&utm_campaign=same_for_all&utm_content=enrollment-email-01&utm_medium=co-enrollment-email&utm_source=enrollment&utm_term=enrollment-button
```

I thought the issue could have been the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829252/measurement-protocol-events-showing-up-in-ga-real-time-dashboard-but-not-content), but according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid) I don't need to include client id if user id is supplied so I think I'm good there?

Any suggestions for how to figure this out would be super appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same problem. All my views and events are tracked in real view, but not the actual report.

I tried a bunch of things then i went to re-read the documentation a little bit clearer: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

Looks like we do need to include the `cid`. After i added that in, my data started rolling in. I used the same value as the uid, and everything seems to work well.